# ¿Como habilito o conozco mi IP publica de SQL Server para conectarme remotamente desde otra red?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, web, localhost

Tengo unas bases de datos locales y se verifican mediante SQL server, estas estan en distintos equipos y en distintas redes, mediante SQL server habilite la conexion remota a las bases de datos, las quiero conectar a un host en linea, pero como la IP que tengo es local no me deja conectarla, como averiguo la ip publica y poder conectarla a travez de internet, adjunto un codigo de como lo estoy haciendo:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.18"; // Reemplaza con la dirección IP o nombre del servidor SQL Server
$database = "Innovacion";
$username = "Login";
$password = "admin123";

try {
    // Utiliza la cadena de conexión para MySQL
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Conexión establecida correctamente";

    // Realiza consultas o acciones en la base de datos aquí

    // Cierra la conexión cuando hayas terminado
    $conn = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

cabe decir que mi host en linea solo acepta PDO y PDO_MySQL, ademas de que el servidor en el que esta alojado es Linux

Comment: quieres acceder a tu base de datos local desde un host en linea? creo es mas facil crear tu base de datos en el host y listo.

Comment: ¿Distintas redes?, ¿Qué infraestructura/arquitectura de red tienes?, ¿Cómo se conectan a internet?. ¿Has probado con [whatsmyip.org](https://whatsmyip.org)?